# W2UI Grid selects entire row when clicked, how to select single cell or column for copying?

Tags: javascript, w2ui

Running into an issue with the W2UI grid.

Goal: I'd like to be able to select an entire column and copy/paste it to Gsheets. Alternately I'd like to be able to click a single cell and copy it's contents too.

Issue: When clicking it selects the entire row including all irrelevant columns, and copying that includes headers too, meaning it has to be cleaned manually before it can be inserted into a spreadsheet.

The "editable" property allows me to select a single cells contents but even that's not quite what I'm looking for as it required 2 clicks, highlighting text then copying, adding 3-4 button presses to the process.

Can't seem to find the answer on how to fix this in the documentation but I may just be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You could (temporarily) switch the select type from `row` (default) to `cell`.

Just make sure to remove any existing row selection first, otherwise it may look confusing.

Assuming your grid is named `grid`:

```
w2ui.grid.selectNone();
w2ui.grid.selectType = 'cell';
w2ui.grid.refresh();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yghueLxp/

**Option 2:**

There's also a new (undocumented) feature to add a copy icon to whole columns - also demonstrated in the linked fiddle, on the first column.

All you have to do is add `clipboardCopy: true` to the column properties.

For this new feature you'll have to use the `dist` files of the current github master - it's **not** available in w2ui 1.5 RC.

By the way, you can make the grid behave similar to an Excel sheet, allowing copy & paste of multiple cells, see: [Spreadsheet Like JavaScript Grid](http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#!combo/combo-3)

> I'd like to be able to [...] paste it to Gsheets

The copied values are TAB separated. This works well when you copy&paste to/from MS Excel. I don't know about Gsheets.

Comment: Thanks, after playing around with it a bit option 1 of setting selectType = 'cell' works pretty much perfectly - except when multiple rows share a recid, in which case it only selects each recid once - but I'm guessing that means I'm using recid incorrectly and the solution is perfect.